# image first or text content first?

Tags: website-design, design-patterns, image, tutorial, walkthrough

Lets consider the following senario:
I'm building a website for a mobile application and I have to create a text/image walkthrough for new users.
Should I set first the text content and then add the image that is reffering to the text's content or vice versa??

According to [that question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16959/which-is-more-likely-to-be-read-and-processed-related-text-placed-above-or-be) I should use image first, and text after(something like caption).

But 1)text and image on a tutorial-like page, both have the same importance and 2) I may use 6-10 images on the same page, so it seems logical that I could set text first and image as an explanation.

So should image be used first, or text??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can the one survive without the other?

If you leave out the text, will people still understand the walkthrough?
And vice versa, will people still understand the walkthrough if you leave out the images?

This way you can determine which content is primary.

If your images tell the whole story I would show the images first and support those with text. This works best if the text are just short sentences, one per image like some image caption.

If your text tells it all I would place that first and later add the images to visually support the text.

Answer (score 0):

The image goes first if it demonstrates the objective you're after and the text is just a caption for it.

The text should be first when it describes what you want the users to know, while the image is only demonstrative and plain.